# Content is overflowing

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsiveness

I have created a home page when I try to open it in mobile view the content is overflowing what might be the reason

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I think I have done mistake in padding. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please frame your question according to the guidelines.
Nevertheless, I would advise you to inspect the page and view which element is extending. For additional visual clarity, try adding this to your CSS:

```* {
    border: 0.5px solid red;
}```

Comment: Hi, we can’t know from just a picture what is causing the problem. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and if possible create a runnable snippet which shows the problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Thanks